# Numpy use one array as mask for another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, mask

I am trying to do these steps in NumPy.  It was easy to do this with python list `sort()`, and `argsort()`.

How do I do this in Numpy?

```
a = np.array([10,30,20,40,50])

a_sorted = np.array([10,20,30,40,50])
```

Get mask of a_sorted

```
b = np.array(['one','three','two','four','five'])
```

Apply the mask to b

Expected array sorted according to a_sorted:

```
b_sorted = np.array(['one','two','three','four','five'])
```

Comment: What is the issue? Where are you using `a_sorted`? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @jared b comes out as sorted independently. Not as per a_sorted masked.

Comment: What you expect is not really clear. What is the relation between `a`, `a_sorted`, `b` and `b_sorted`?

Comment: Is `a_sorted` the result of `a[np.argsort(a)]`?

Comment: @Corralien Updated the Q. `b` can be any values, number, chars. They need to be rearranged according to `a_sorted`

Comment: The mask of `a_sorted` is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] so the result of `b[np.argsort(a_sorted)]` gives the same output as `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([10, 30, 20, 40, 50])
a_sorted_indices = np.argsort(a)
a_sorted = a[a_sorted_indices]

b = np.array(['one', 'three', 'two', 'four', 'five'])

b_sorted = b[a_sorted_indices]

print("Sorted array 'a':", a_sorted)
print("Sorted array 'b':", b_sorted)
```

Output:

```
Sorted array 'a': [10 20 30 40 50]
Sorted array 'b': ['one' 'two' 'three' 'four' 'five']
```